# Alert when docker container pod is in Error or CarshLoopBackOff kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have my kubernetes cluster setup on AWS where I am trying to monitor several pods, using cAdvisor + Prometheus + Alert manager. What I want to do it launch an email alert (with service/container name) if a container/pod goes down or stuck in Error or CarshLoopBackOff state or stcuk in anyother state apart from running.

Comment: `CarshLoopBackOff`? Or `CrashLoopBackOff`?

Answer (score 15):

Prometheus collects [a wide range of metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/docs/pod-metrics.md). As an example, you can use a metric `kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total` for monitoring restarts, which will reflect your problem.

It containing tags which you can use in the alert:

- container=`container-name`
- namespace=`pod-namespace`
- pod=`pod-name`

So, everything you need is to configure your `alertmanager.yaml` [config](https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/blob/master/doc/examples/simple.yml) by adding correct SMTP settings, receiver and rules like that:

```
global:
  # The smarthost and SMTP sender used for mail notifications.
  smtp_smarthost: 'localhost:25'
  smtp_from: 'alertmanager@example.org'
  smtp_auth_username: 'alertmanager'
  smtp_auth_password: 'password'

receivers:
- name: 'team-X-mails'
  email_configs:
  - to: 'team-X+alerts@example.org'

# Only one default receiver
route:
  receiver: team-X-mails

# Example group with one alert
groups:
- name: example-alert
  rules:
    # Alert about restarts
  - alert: RestartAlerts
    expr: count(kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total) by (pod-name) > 5
    for: 10m
    annotations:
      summary: "More than 5 restarts in pod {{ $labels.pod-name }}"
      description: "{{ $labels.container-name }} restarted (current value: {{ $value }}s) times in pod {{ $labels.pod-namespace }}/{{ $labels.pod-name }}"
```

Comment: You mean if a pod is stuck in Crashloopbackoff it means it will restart multiple  to recover from this state “Crashloopbackoff” ? Also how to monitor if Prometheus pods(server,alertmanager) itself stuck in this state ?

Comment: 1. Yes, here is an example of the state in that situation - `nfs-web-fdr9h      0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   8          16m`. So, 8 here - is a count of restarts. 2. Yes, it monitors themselves, because they are pods too. However, of course, Prometheus and Alertmanager can watch itself and send an alert when they are working. If they are down - who will send an alert?:)

Comment: when i run kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total in prometheus databse it gives me "no Data"  i have killed kube-dns pod and recreated new one though

Comment: Check that you have a [kube-state-metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics) installed in your cluster. Btw, here is another one [set of rules](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/blob/master/contrib/kube-prometheus/assets/prometheus/rules/kube-state-metrics.rules.yaml) which can be helpful.

Comment: i do have kube-state-metrics running

Comment: Shouldn't `pod-name` rather just be `pod`? Same for `container-name` etc...?

Comment: Doesn't "count" take to account all the occurances "EVER" of the pod being restarted ?
Wouldnt `sum by (pod) (increase(kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total[5m])) > 2` be better because well, it might have restarted, but if it recovered - all is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this one :

```
    - alert: PodCrashLooping
  annotations:
    description: Pod {{ $labels.namespace }}/{{ $labels.pod }} ({{ $labels.container }}) is restarting {{ printf "%.2f" $value }} times / 5 minutes.
    summary: Pod is crash looping.
  expr: rate(kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total{job="kube-state-metrics",namespace=~".*"}[5m]) * 60 * 5 > 0
  for: 5m
  labels:
    severity: critical
```