# Prometheus Operator Alertmanager - Custom rule - field groups not found in type config.plain

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have installed prometheus-operator via helm and now want to set custom alert rule, email notifications are set up, currently i'm getting every notification, i want to "silence it" so i can get emails for custom alerts.

alertmanager.yaml:

```
global:
  resolve_timeout: 5m
route:
  receiver: 'email-alert'
  group_by: ['job']


  routes:
  - receiver: 'email-alert'
    match:
      alertname: etcdInsufficientMembers
    group_wait: 30s
    group_interval: 5m
    repeat_interval: 12h  

receivers:
- name: email-alert
  email_configs:
  - to: receiver@example.com
    from: sender@example.com
    # Your smtp server address
    smarthost: smtp.office365.com:587
    auth_username: sender@example.com
    auth_identity: sender@example.com
    auth_password: pass
```

Above file is applied sucessfully,

i added following lines at the end of above file, as referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49472375/alert-when-docker-container-pod-is-in-error-or-carshloopbackoff-kubernetes):

```
# Example group with one alert

groups:
- name: example-alert
  rules:
    # Alert about restarts
  - alert: RestartAlerts
    expr: count(kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total) > 0
    for: 1s
    annotations:
      summary: "More than 5 restarts in pod {{ $labels.pod-name }}"
      description: "{{ $labels.container-name }} restarted (current value: {{ $value }}s) times in pod {{ $labels.pod-namespace }}/{{ $labels.pod-name }}
```

And then in pod logs i'm getting this:

```
="Loading configuration file failed" file=/etc/alertmanager/config/alertmanager.yaml err="yaml: unmarshal errors:\n  line 28: field groups not found in type config.plain"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, first, need to list all available rules:

```
    kubectl -n monitoring get prometheusrules
NAME                                                              AGE
prometheus-prometheus-oper-alertmanager.rules                     29h
prometheus-prometheus-oper-etcd                                   29h
prometheus-prometheus-oper-general.rules                          29h
prometheus-prometheus-oper-k8s.rules                              29h
prometheus-prometheus-oper-kube-apiserver-error                   29h
prometheus-prometheus-oper-kube-apiserver.rules                   29h
prometheus-prometheus-oper-kube-prometheus-node-recording.rules   29h
prometheus-prometheus-oper-kube-scheduler.rules                   29h
prometheus-prometheus-oper-kubernetes-absent                      29h
prometheus-prometheus-oper-kubernetes-apps                        29h
prometheus-prometheus-oper-kubernetes-resources                   29h
prometheus-prometheus-oper-kubernetes-storage                     29h
prometheus-prometheus-oper-kubernetes-system                      29h
prometheus-prometheus-oper-kubernetes-system-apiserver            29h
prometheus-prometheus-oper-kubernetes-system-controller-manager   29h
prometheus-prometheus-oper-kubernetes-system-kubelet              29h
prometheus-prometheus-oper-kubernetes-system-scheduler            29h
prometheus-prometheus-oper-node-exporter                          29h
prometheus-prometheus-oper-node-exporter.rules                    29h
prometheus-prometheus-oper-node-network                           29h
prometheus-prometheus-oper-node-time                              29h
prometheus-prometheus-oper-node.rules                             29h
prometheus-prometheus-oper-prometheus                             29h
prometheus-prometheus-oper-prometheus-operator                    29h
```

Then choose one to edit, or delete all except default one: `prometheus-prometheus-oper-general.rules`

i choose to edit node-exporter rule

```
kubectl edit prometheusrule prometheus-prometheus-oper-node-exporter -n monitoring
```

Added these lines at the end of file

```
- alert: RestartAlerts
  annotations:
    description: '{{ $labels.container }} restarted (current value: {{ $value}}s)
          times in pod {{ $labels.namespace }}/{{ $labels.pod }}'
    summary: More than 5 restarts in pod {{ $labels.container }}
  expr: kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total{container="coredns"} > 5
  for: 1min
  labels:
    severity: warning
```

And soon after, i received email for this alert.